# pip install chromedriver only installed python bindings

Tags: python-3.x, pip, selenium-chromedriver

When I use the command "pip install chromedriver" and checked the directory. It installed a directory named "chromedriver" and only have **init**.py and  **pycache** inside, rather than a executable file.

Is this because some errors of my environment and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the name of the package you want to install rather `chromedriver_installer`. So try to install `chromedriver_installer` with `pip install chromedriver_installer` and see if this works.